# Error installing @tensorflow/tfjs-node using npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, tensorflow.js

Command:

```
npm i @tensorflow/tfjs-node
```

Output:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Aarat Batra\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\dogBreed\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! CPU-windows-4.13.0.zip
npm ERR! https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-2.9.1.zip
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\Aarat Batra\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\dogBreed\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v8\tfjs_binding.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.13.0/CPU-windows-4.13.0.zip
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.13.0/CPU-windows-4.13.0.zip
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for @tensorflow/tfjs-node@4.13.0 and node@18.16.0 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.13.0/CPU-windows-4.13.0.zip       
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.11 found at "C:\Users\Aarat Batra\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:369:14)     
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:390:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:427:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\Aarat Batra\\Dropbox\\PC\\Desktop\\dogBreed\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v8\\tfjs_binding.node" "--module_name=tfjs_binding" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Aarat Batra\\Dropbox\\PC\\Desktop\\dogBreed\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v8" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=8" "--node_napi_label=napi-v8"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Aarat Batra\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\dogBreed\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Aarat Batra\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\dogBreed\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v8\tfjs_binding.node --module_name=tfjs_binding --module_path=C:\Users\Aarat Batra\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\dogBreed\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v8 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=8 --node_napi_label=napi-v8' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aarat Batra\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\dogBreed\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Aarat Batra\\Dropbox\\PC\\Desktop\\dogBreed\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Aarat Batra\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\dogBreed\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.16.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! * Downloading libtensorflow
npm ERR!
npm ERR! * Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aarat Batra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-26T09_29_43_709Z-debug-0.log
```

I am trying to install @tensorflow/tfjs-node package to use in my node js server and everytime it shows me this error. I tried to install visual studio but it is or more than 6gb and still there is no guarentee that it will work. My objective is to load a model.json file and create a tensor from image pixel data of 3 channels (rgb) and supply it to this model and do model.predict. All of it can be done via tfjs only but it does not support tf.node.decodeImage and I cannot find any alternative for this using tfjs. There is one though but it creates a wrong input. Anyway, if there is a way to install tfjs-node and use it without downloading a heavy 6gb+ software, please mention.